# How to unblock/place behind my autosuggest panel

Tags: php, css

Good Day Everyone!

I have search panel where i can do advance and basic
Example below

***Basic***
[image]

***Advance***
[image]

Then I apply a Auto-suggest on my field.

[image]

As you notice there's more auto suggest value after "Marina Diamonds"
But you can see my .main class blocking the autosuggest value.

Here's my code

**.main class**

```
   .main {
    z-index: 5;
   }
```

so I can hide my search panel when on Basic

Then on auto suggest i have this

```
.easy-autocomplete-container {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I don't have any problem with my basic and advance function. But I have issue on auto suggest because my .main css blocking my auto suggest value. Any solution to place my autosuggest behind my .main so I can see all the suggested list??

Thankyou!

Comment: change your .easy-autocomplete-container z-index to a value more than any other elements z-index

Comment: @AbbasNabilou I tried but issue still persist.

Comment: so it may be because of overflow: hidden of the parent element... check this too